# How to prove this function is continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

$\gamma:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, is continuously differentiable.

Define $F:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{\gamma(x)-\gamma(y)}{x-y} - \gamma'(x)$  if $x\not=y$ and $0$ if $x=y$.

Then is $F$ continuous? It seems true, but I couldn't justify continuity of $F$ about the line $x=y$.

Comment: Hint: Its the difference quotients. Approaching the limit on the $x=y$ line gives you the derivative.

Comment: @F.Conrad To prove continuity of a function of two variables, you have to consider the limit along any possible path. Continuity of $\gamma'$ is essential here as well.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what i couldn't prove...